# Error while starting hadoop daemons

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am new to hadoop as well as ubuntu and trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 in (Ubuntu) on my system.
When I tried to start the daemons using start-all.sh or start-dfs.sh, it throws an error saying "Command not found".
I have issued this command as an user created under the hadoop group only.

```
> hduser@nitk-OptiPlex-9010:~/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin$ start-all.sh
> start-all.sh: command not found
```

Can someone please help me out to resolve this issue?

Also when I tried modifying the core-site, **hdfs-site xml** files under **etc/hadoop** folder, core-site.xml~, hdfs-site.xml~ files were created (New files with a tilde symbol at the end of their names got created). I deleted those new files created. Is this creating a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Follow below steps
      ==> Go to hadoop home directory:   cd /usr/local/hadoop/
      ==> Start the process of datanodes and namenodes  : bin/hadoop namenode -format
           ==> Start deamons : sbin/start-dfs.sh (start-all.sh is depreciated)

Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

write `./start-all.sh`

If it says `start-all.sh: command not found`

That means its not yet into executable mode. Change it to executable via chmod

```
chmod +x *.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right way to start deamons is as follows:

1- Using the command line you go to the directory of hadoop

> cd /usr/local/hadoop/

2- Then you start deamons in this way:

> bin/start-all.sh

But I suggest you to delete first all the datanodes and namenode files to start the processes with a clean environment in addition to formatting the namenode

> bin/hadoop namenode -format

Hope that helps you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. First run this command
chmod +x start-dfs.sh
2. then run
/.start-dfs.sh

Answer (score 0):

**Error**: command not found

```
$ /home/user/Documents/installed/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
 start-all.sh command not found
```

**Solution:** Go to the Hadoop install location and then run:

```
$ cd /home/user/Documents/installed/hadoop/sbin
$ ./start-all.sh 
$ jps

12373 Jps
11823 SecondaryNameNode
11643 DataNode
12278 NodeManager
11974 ResourceManager
11499 NameNode
```