# Cloudera Hadoop - Daemons not running

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm, bigdata

I'm self learning Hadoop and started of with installing [Cloudera QuickVM](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-4.html) on a VMware Workstation running CENT OS.

I was under the impression that `Quickstart VM` has most the of configurations predefined. Do I need to set up any other configurations to set up data and name node? Reason being when I type JFS I get only

```
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ jps </n>

9480 RunJar </n>

18607 Jps 6952 </n>

org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

I don't see any data nodes nor name nodes.I looked it up online and solution was to start the daemons using `start-all.sh`. But I get an error

```
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop]$ start-all.sh

bash: start-all.sh: command not found
```

Another round of research landed me in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318205/error-while-starting-hadoop-daemons)

As suggested in that answer, when I ran `bin/hadoop namenode -format`

```
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop]$ bin/hadoop namenode -format

bash: bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

I'm stuck in the middle of nowhere with motivation for self study getting really low. Please help with a suggestion and raise up my spirits.

P.S.: I'm an extreme beginner on Hadoop, so please don't be harsh on me if the question looks stupid to you :)

Comment: Try this : [CDH Install Config](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~mwang2/projects/CDH_installConfig2_13m.pdf)   &  [cloudera-quickstart](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/PDF/cloudera-quickstart.pdf)
hope it will help you to get started.

Comment: When I use the Quickstart VM, I just use Cloudera Manager for messing with all services.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough power / resources to use the Cloudera manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out how to start services on cloudera quickstart vm with some help from the community.

```
service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
```

Now when i run `JPS`, I can see all the daemons running,

> ```
> [root@quickstart cloudera]# jps
> 2374 JobHistoryServer
> 2070 NameNode
> 3294 RunJar
> 4445 Bootstrap
> 4803 
> 2947 -- process information unavailable
> 2196 SecondaryNameNode
> 1840 QuorumPeerMain
> 1908 DataNode
> 4836 
> 3094 RunJar
> 3777 Master
> 2865 RESTServer
> 2594 ResourceManager
> 2327 Bootstrap
> 3663 Bootstrap
> 2451 NodeManager
> 1999 JournalNode
> 3111 Jps
> 3684 HistoryServer
> 4784 Bootstrap
> ```

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are in the **correct folder**? Try using `ls` to see the folder contents.

```
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop]$ start-all.sh
bash: start-all.sh: command not found

[cloudera@quickstart hadoop]$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
bash: bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

This pretty much says that you are in the wrong folder. **No such file or directory.**

Make sure to learn the basics of using the bash shell, too. Such as `ls -l start-all.sh` to see if the file exists that you are trying to run; and to see the file *permissions*.

Comment: `start-all.sh` is usually in the PATH for self-installed Hadoop environments. The Cloudera VM does it differently; that is where the confusion in the question is coming from

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand from the error that the folder is not present but my question is do I need to configure anything in the cloudera quickstart vm? As far I know the cloudera vm is all configured and ready to run.

Comment: @cricket_007 well, it is not in the `PATH` here, obviously.

Comment: I can see that. But providing an answer pointing that out isn't very helpful, is all I'm saying

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes sir, precisely. I was looking out for people who might have worked on cloudera quickstart vm who could be able to help on where it has been customized in cloudera's version.

Comment: You should probably contact Cloudera if you have questions about clouderas software? http://community.cloudera.com/

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did but no proper response yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below mentioned command. It will give you list of locations.

```
find / -type f -name start-all.sh
```

cd /path_name then try running command,

```
./start-all.sh
```